# VideoTexture is not playing in VR

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, webvr

At first the texture works fine and the video plays as expected, but when VR is entered via `VRDisplay.requestPresent` it stops. Why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VR display has its own render loop. Usually `needsUpdate` is automatically set to `true` on every animation frame by *three.js*, but this is only true for the default display.

To fix this, get the VR display from the `vrdisplayconnect` event and create your own update loop. E.g.

```
let display = e.display;
```

```
let displayUpdateLoop = () =>
{
    // May get a warning if getFrameData is not called.
    let frameData = new VRFrameData();
    display.getFrameData(frameData);

    videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;

    // Stop loop if no longer presenting.
    if (display.isPresenting)
        display.requestAnimationFrame(displayUpdateLoop);
}
display.requestAnimationFrame(displayUpdateLoop);
```